# Migrating solr to solr with no end result. Try to fill new field in source Solr core

Tags: solr, lucene, dataimporthandler

I have target Solr 5.5.0(local) and source Solr 4.10.2(local). After migration process there no rows in target Solr. Who knowns what am i doing wrong?

There are 2 cores, core1 (source) and core2 (target). All fields in both are identically. BUT, i have a new field (stored, indexed) in source core, that must be filled by copyfield.

Here's data-config.xml (stored fields only):

```
<dataConfig>
  <document>
    <entity name="oldRow" processor="SolrEntityProcessor" url="http://localhost:8984/solr/core1" query="*:*">
        <field column="_version_" name="_version_" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field column="id" name="id" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field column="type" name="type" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field column="field2" name="field2" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <field column="field3" name="field3" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        ...
    </entity>
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Here is schemas (both):

```
...
<fields>
  <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"     required="true"/>

  <field name="field1" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="field2" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
  <field name="field3" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
  ...
  </fields>
  <!--  unique key-->
  <uniqueKey>uid</uniqueKey>
  ...
```

and unique key consists of 2 fields:

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="dedupe">
<processor class="org.apache.solr.update.processor.SignatureUpdateProcessorFactory">
  <bool name="enabled">true</bool>
  <bool name="overwriteDupes">true</bool>
  <str name="signatureField">uid</str>
  <str name="fields">id,type</str>
  <str name="signatureClass">org.apache.solr.update.processor.Lookup3Signature</str>
</processor>
<processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
<processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
</updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

Import Handler:

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="skip-fields">
<processor class="solr.IgnoreFieldUpdateProcessorFactory"> 
    <str name="fieldRegex">_version_</str>
</processor>
</updateRequestProcessorChain>

<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
<lst name="defaults">
  <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
  <str name="update.chain">skip-fields</str>
</lst>
</requestHandler>
```

And log after import (try to import 1 row):

```
2016-03-10 05:47:41.552 INFO  (qtp859417998-21) [   x:core2] o.a.s.h.d.DataImporter Loading DIH Configuration: data-config.xml
2016-03-10 05:47:41.580 INFO  (qtp859417998-21) [   x:core2] o.a.s.h.d.DataImporter Data Configuration loaded successfully
2016-03-10 05:47:41.581 INFO  (qtp859417998-21) [   x:core2] o.a.s.h.d.DataImporter Starting Full Import
2016-03-10 05:47:41.598 INFO  (qtp859417998-21) [   x:core2] o.a.s.h.d.SimplePropertiesWriter Read dataimport.properties
2016-03-10 05:47:41.683 INFO  (qtp859417998-21) [   x:core2] o.a.s.h.d.SolrEntityProcessor using BinaryResponseParser
2016-03-10 05:47:41.821 INFO  (qtp859417998-21) [   x:core2] o.a.s.h.d.DocBuilder Indexing stopped at docCount = 1
2016-03-10 05:47:41.822 INFO  (qtp859417998-21) [   x:core2] o.a.s.h.d.DocBuilder Import completed successfully
2016-03-10 05:47:41.823 INFO  (qtp859417998-21) [   x:core2] o.a.s.h.d.SimplePropertiesWriter Read dataimport.properties
2016-03-10 05:47:41.827 INFO  (qtp859417998-21) [   x:core2] o.a.s.h.d.SimplePropertiesWriter Wrote last indexed time to dataimport.properties
2016-03-10 05:47:41.828 INFO  (qtp859417998-21) [   x:core2] o.a.s.h.d.DocBuilder Time taken = 0:0:0.229
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. you have to rename field "*version*" to anything else to ignore it. "*version*" is an internal field, for concurrent locking / updating purposes. You can't update with a different "*version*"-content, than is in the db. So kill the field by renaming in dataconfig tag
field column="*version*" name="_old_version_" 
Peter

```
<dataConfig>
<document>
<entity name="oldRow" processor="SolrEntityProcessor" url="http://localhost:8984/solr/core1" query="*:*">
<field column="_version_" name="_old_version_" />
    ...
</entity>
</document>
</dataConfig>
```